# WCF calling a external service - communication faulted state

Tags: wcf

I´m building a winform client using VS 2013. I want to consume a 3party java secure and external (using https with certificate) web service.

I have access to the wsdl. I added a service reference to my .net project referencing the address of the Endpoint and I configured my web.config with wsHttpBinding and transport. ( I have also tried with basicHttpBinding )

In code, I create a client service object and I can see its methods and data types normally.

I have seen that as soon as I create the object, the InnerChannel property is in faulted state mode and I do not understand why.

[Show my code in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhui3.jpg)

The problem is that when calling any of the service object methods, It gives the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Additional information: The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1
>   [myproyect.SR.NotificaWsPortType], can not be used for communication
>   because it is in the Faulted state.
>
> Additional information: There was an error reflecting 'return'.

Can anybody help me?

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>

    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="NotificaWsBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://<address here>"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NotificaWsBinding"
            contract="SR.NotificaWsPortType" name="NotificaWsPort" />
    </client>

</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: *I configured...wsHttpBinding and transport* - you should not be using this binding because it is not interoperable. Use basicHttpBinding instead. This should have been chosen for you when you consumed the service metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Initially I used basicHttpBinding but it does not work either. I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. There was a problem mapping the webservice in .NET because the webservice was developed in java and had a problem whit microsoft technology.
So I spoke with the service providers and they did not have any problems with java but with .net. They changed something in their internals and it worked for me.